# Convert forEach without deprecated for-loop?

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm using a `forEach` statement, but I'd like to convert it into a `for-loop`. However, the C-style `for-loop` is deprecated now.

Here is what I'm trying to convert:

```
items.indices.forEach { fromIndex in
  ...
}
```

How can I use a `for-loop` that is forward-compatible?

Comment: `for index in items.indices { ... }` – but what is wrong with `forEach`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Good question, I need to break out of the loop and doesn't seem possible with `forEach`. When using `return`, it only breaks out of the current cycle, not the whole loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of this:

```
let arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
let startIndex = 3
let increment = 2

for var i in startIndex..<arr.count {
    print(arr[i], terminator: " ") //d e f g
}

for i in startIndex.stride(to: arr.count, by: increment) {
    print(i, terminator: " ") //d f
}

for (index, element) in arr.enumerate() {
    print(index, terminator: " ") //d f a b c d e f g
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [good article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift2-2) I found for the changes in Swift 2.2.

As for your question if you want to use the traditional c style loop, the new syntax would be:

```
for var i in 0..<items.indices.count {
    print("index: \(i)")
}
```